# Update SQL Column based on Column within same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with some data which needs updating on a SQL table "Locations" for a client.

I need to do a search on column A "City" which will have names, say "Sydney", "Melbourne", "Perth" in the fields. Anything that states "Melbourne" needs column D "Risk" updating from having value "1" to having value "3".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. You can try this:

```
UPDATE Locations
SET Risk = 3
WHERE City = 'Melbourne' AND Risk = 1
```